# Using the GPU with Lux and NeuralPDE Julia

Tags: neural-network, julia, pde, flux.jl, differentialequations.jl

I am trying to run a model using the GPU, no problem with the CPU.  I think somehow using measured boundary conditions is causing the issue but I am not sure.  I am following this example:  https://docs.sciml.ai/dev/modules/NeuralPDE/tutorials/gpu/.  I am following this example for using measured boundary conditions: https://docs.sciml.ai/dev/modules/MethodOfLines/tutorials/icbc_sampled/

```
using Random
using NeuralPDE, Lux, CUDA, Random
using Optimization
using OptimizationOptimisers
using NNlib
import ModelingToolkit: Interval
using Interpolations

# Measured Boundary Conditions (Arbitrary For Example)
bc1 = 1.0:1:1001.0 .|> Float32
bc2 = 1.0:1:1001.0 .|> Float32
ic1 = zeros(101) .|> Float32
ic2 = zeros(101) .|> Float32;

# Interpolation Functions Registered as Symbolic
itp1 = interpolate(bc1, BSpline(Cubic(Line(OnGrid()))))
up_cond_1_f(t::Float32) = itp1(t)
@register_symbolic up_cond_1_f(t)

itp2 = interpolate(bc2, BSpline(Cubic(Line(OnGrid()))))
up_cond_2_f(t::Float32) = itp2(t)
@register_symbolic up_cond_2_f(t)

itp3 = interpolate(ic1, BSpline(Cubic(Line(OnGrid()))))
init_cond_1_f(x::Float32) = itp3(x)
@register_symbolic init_cond_1_f(x)

itp4 = interpolate(ic2, BSpline(Cubic(Line(OnGrid()))))
init_cond_2_f(x::Float32) = itp4(x)
@register_symbolic init_cond_2_f(x);

# Parameters and differentials
@parameters t, x
@variables u1(..), u2(..)
Dt = Differential(t)
Dx = Differential(x);

# Arbitrary Equations
eqs = [Dt(u1(t, x)) + Dx(u2(t, x)) ~ 0.,
       Dt(u1(t, x)) * u1(t,x) + Dx(u2(t, x)) + 9.81 ~ 0.] 

# Boundary Conditions with Measured Data
bcs = [
       u1(t,1) ~ up_cond_1_f(t),
       u2(t,1) ~ up_cond_2_f(t),
       u1(1,x) ~ init_cond_1_f(x),
       u2(1,x) ~ init_cond_2_f(x)
]

# Space and time domains
domains = [t ∈ Interval(1.0,1001.0),
           x ∈ Interval(1.0,101.0)];

# Neural network
input_ = length(domains)
n = 10
chain = Chain(Dense(input_,n,NNlib.tanh_fast),Dense(n,n,NNlib.tanh_fast),Dense(n,4))

strategy = GridTraining(.25)
ps = Lux.setup(Random.default_rng(), chain)[1]
ps = ps |> Lux.ComponentArray |> gpu .|> Float32

discretization = PhysicsInformedNN(chain,
                                   strategy,
                                   init_params=ps)

# Model Setup
@named pdesystem = PDESystem(eqs,bcs,domains,[t,x],[u1(t, x),u2(t, x)])
prob = discretize(pdesystem,discretization);
sym_prob = symbolic_discretize(pdesystem,discretization);

# Losses and Callbacks
pde_inner_loss_functions = sym_prob.loss_functions.pde_loss_functions
bcs_inner_loss_functions = sym_prob.loss_functions.bc_loss_functions

callback = function (p, l)
    println("loss: ", l)
    println("pde_losses: ", map(l_ -> l_(p), pde_inner_loss_functions))
    println("bcs_losses: ", map(l_ -> l_(p), bcs_inner_loss_functions))
    return false
end;

# Train Model (Throws Error)
res = Optimization.solve(prob,Adam(0.01); callback = callback, maxiters=5000)
phi = discretization.phi;
```

I get the following error:

```
GPU broadcast resulted in non-concrete element type Union{}.
This probably means that the function you are broadcasting contains an error or type instability.
```

Please Advise.